# linux motherboard dump recovery

Tags: linux-kernel, embedded-linux, motherboard

I vaguely remember a kernel extension where the last few KB of logging was saved to some ram on suitable motherboards.  This let you recover the dump from an oops/panic on the next boot.  Very useful for server farms.

Does anyone remember what that extension was called?  Or the motherboard feature to have that storage.

Is there a way to set aside some RAM and save it there instead (for an embedded system)?

Answer (score 3):

Originally this was the feature of Android kernel called [RAM console](https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/common.git/+/android-3.4/drivers/staging/android/ram_console.c). It can be enabled using [CONFIG_ANDROID_RAM_CONSOLE](https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/common.git/+/android-3.4/drivers/staging/android/Kconfig#34) option.

Now the similar mechanism called [pstore](http://lwn.net/Articles/421297/) is available in mainline kernel (was added by [this](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=ca01d6dd2d7a2652000307520777538740efc286) commit). You can enable it using [CONFIG_PSTORE_*](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/fs/pstore/Kconfig?id=refs/tags/v4.5-rc3) options.

More details about RAM console upstreaming can be found [here](http://elinux.org/Android_Mainlining_Project#Patch.2FFeature_Status_Chart).